# Is it a TouchKeyboard bug in Delphi Alexandria 11.3?

Tags: delphi, keyboard, vcl, shift

I dropped a `TouchKeyboard` from palette into a form, and I ran the program.

When I clicked with mouse on the left Shift (down&up) on `TouchKeyboard`, and then clicked the right Shift, everything seemed alright. However, after I clicked the right Shift again, letters remain to be lower case. Actually, I noticed that they were upper-case at the moment, but then they quickly got lowered. It seems that the third click caused code to send 2 clicks.

This is just one version of unexpected behavior. As a general rule, if I click one modifier (Shift, Ctrl, Alt) to toggle it on, and then the opposite modifier to toggle off, then whatever clicks I do--if any--and go back to click any modifier of the same type, then this unexpected behavior happens.

Comment: Have you compared this behavior with the built in windows keyboard?

Comment: That is definitely a bug.  I can recreate it in Delphi 11.2 as well. Window built-in keyboard does not have such behavior. I suspect the component isn't syncing the state of left and right modifier keys properly. While it seems to update visual state OK it doesn't seem to properly sync the internal state of such buttons. I did try debugging the `TTouchKeyboard` code in order to track this bug but for some reason it always crashes the debugger so it stops responding to any debug points until I shut down the application and restart. It is like debugger would detach from the process.

Comment: Having a bug in software is very, very important to know! Appreciate your answer.